# Inno Setup: How to change background color

Tags: colors, inno-setup

Is there a way to change the background color of the Inno Setup bottom panel to white color?

Thanks for your help!

[image: InnoSetup Footer]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That bottom panel that you described is actually the area of the Wizard form, and so you can just set the `Color` property of the `WizardForm` object itself:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.Color := clWhite;
end;
```

There's yet one more thing worth mentioning; though the above code shows how to set that area color to a constant white as you asked, what you can see on your screenshot as white is actually a color given by the Windows theme, so that color must not always be white. So if your aim was to have the same color as the page you're currently on, then you should rather inherit the color from the parent pages:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  case CurPageID of
    wpWelcome: WizardForm.Color := WizardForm.WelcomePage.Color;
    wpFinished: WizardForm.Color := WizardForm.FinishedPage.Color;
  else
    WizardForm.Color := WizardForm.InnerPage.Color;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You're welcome! I've added some talk about the white color :)

Comment: See also follow up question, [Changing background color of task list box and other controls in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52441557/850848).

Comment: Another related question: [How to change background color of SelectDirBitmapImage and SelectGroupBitmapImage in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61083816/850848).