# Inno Setup: How to change uninstall background color

Tags: windows, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to figure out how to change the background color of the bottom panel in the UNINSTALLER to match the colors I was able to set for the INSTALLER using information I found here:  [Inno Setup: How to change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557034/inno-setup-how-to-change-background-color)  Unfortunately, I have been unable to find any way to extend that answer to include the uninstall page, too.  It works great for the install, but when I test the uninstall I see this:

[image: Ugly output example]

In the installer, when the background color of the lower pane changed, the background of the beveled label changed with it, but I cannot find a similar setting for the uninstaller.  I looked at the list of `CurPageID` values and none seem related to the uninstaller, though I would expect it to either be listed or use the same settings as the installer.  Sadly, neither seem to be true.

Can anyone please explain the right way to do this?  Thanks!

EDIT:  For anyone who doesn't want to look at the code from the linked article, here's the way it looks right now in my project:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  WizardForm.Color := WizardForm.InnerPage.Color;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.Color := clWhite;
end;
```

I originally tried it without commenting out the lines in `CurPageChanged`, then I thought, why not ALWAYS set the color on a page change.  Still, the uninstall pages have a gray lower pane. Apparently, the code doesn't affect them and/or they are not `WizardForm` pages.

EDIT:  When asked to show the code I had tried, I added the block of code as it looked at the time.  That block included some commented out lines that were part of previous attempts.  Someone here decided that those previous attempts were NOT needed and removed them from my post.  So may I ask, "Why is SOME of my failed code appropriate but other parts of it are not?  Or should I post every single individual version of the functions in the 20-something times I tweaked them before giving up and asking my question?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstaller equivalent of `InitializeWizard` is [`InitializeUninstallProgressForm`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstallProgressForm):

```pascal
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  UninstallProgressForm.Color := clWhite;
end;
```

[image]

---

An equivalent of `CurPageChanged` is [`CurUninstallStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged). The `UninstallProgressForm` is not available in initial `usAppMutexCheck` and final `usDone` steps.

Though you should use the `InitializeUninstallProgressForm` as shown above anyway.