# How to change background color of SelectDirBitmapImage and SelectGroupBitmapImage in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

How to change background color of `SelectDirBitmapImage` and `SelectGroupBitmapImage` in Inno Setup?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardly. Both those are icons with a transparent background from `shell32.dll` painted on the `TBitmapImage` using `SelectDirPage.Color` and `SelectProgramGroupPage.Color` long before any use code is triggered. It cannot be updated. You would have to repeat all the painting code in your Pascal Script. It's probably doable, but lot of work.

The relevant code is in `LoadSelectDirAndGroupImages` function:
https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_0_4-2/Projects/Wizard.pas#L752-L781